# Validate multiple forms hidden with ng-if in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a form with multiple screens that cannot be submitted without all being valid. Basically, I want to hide the forms not currently in use by using `ng-if`, but then the forms are empty and I cannot set validity based on required fields. We are using angularJs 1.3.2.

I built a custom form generator directive. Each form simply has a blueprint and is generated using the directive. So the main form is set up like this (except there are more cases):

```
<ng-form name="form">
  <fieldset ng-form="customerInfo">
    <div ng-if="activeTab === 'Customer Info'" ng-include="'customer-info.view.html'"></div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset ng-form="financialInfo">
    <div ng-if="activeTab === 'Financial Info'" ng-include="'financial-info.view.html'"></div>
  </fieldset>

  <div>
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="onSubmit()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-form>
```

If I use `ng-if`, the form elements are not generated, therefore are not checked for validity. If I use `ng-show`, the page takes a very long time to render.

I would rather not have to set validity in the JavaScript (since I have many models with quite a few conditions that make each of them valid).

Does anyone know an efficient way to handle this?

Comment: ng-show is the only solution that I can think of.  Have you tried to figure out why the page renders so slowly?  If you can figure that out it might be your best bet.

Comment: Seems like the render takes a while because each form step is being generated dynamically. So the processing on each form takes a fairly short amount of time (<1s), but to render all of them (there are about 8) takes 3-4s.

Answer (score 0):

I Jurchfield,

My suggestion is not rendered all the forms in unique view. For a better approach creates a multi-step form using `ng-form`. This will allow you to validate each individually without having to worry about the other sections (Integrate routing and validation from the controller).

Comment: I found a way to effectivly speed up the rendering process. I call an `onRendered()` function that marks one page loaded, and I added an `ng-if` to the rest of the pages that is conditional based on one of the screens being rendered. That way the first form loads, followed by the remaining forms.